# How do I properly load a PSD in GIMP?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, gimp

I wanted to load up free PSD's from TurboSquid.com, they are royalty free, and they encourage the downloads...
But I CAN NOT, load them up in GIMP at all. All they show is a WHITE screen when i load it into gimp.
I have GIMP v2.8.16, and I have tried to drag and drop, or manually load, or open with on the file itself. Nothing seems to actually want to open it up nothing... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no hidden layers or anything? Tried running gimp in a terminal & watch for errors, especially with `-c, --console-messages`?

Comment: Nope no hidden layers, or anything.  Oddly I did run it in a terminal, and it jut blazed by no errors, it sees it as a good file, no corruptions or anything.  This is a first time I have ever tried to open a PSD in GIMP, so it is new experience for me. It is weird when nothing happens.

Comment: Another idea - the download failed somehow, perhaps silently, still downloading a file with the correct name, but only containing text or HTML. Looked at/in it with a binary/hex editor? I'd expect some errors or some results from trying to open it in gimp though. Maybe try a newer (or older) version of Gimp?

Comment: Did the re downloading, nope.   Never did look at it with a binary/hex to me why would I think of doing that to a picture file...heh good idea though. Not the first thing to enter my mind.   Though I didnt think of trying an older GIMP version.  Since I have the newest, didnt think of going old school heh.

Comment: I've seen a few websites that will quietly send a short HTML page (something like "can't download this") in place of a downloaded file. Misconfigured probably, but it probably won't be the last time it happens. Also try running `file` on the downloaded file, maybe it's something different.

Comment: And what exactly does gimp say when trying to open it? Any error messages, or just a big white canvas? Maybe it's just a blank image. Are the file url's public, feel like sharing them?

Comment: I agree, sadly it is a PSD in a ZIP file so running it is out of the question. I wish I could have done that.    As for the error, there isnt any, it loads up without errors meaning textual, the only error(if it is an error all in all i think it is) i can see is the white 1 layer that is it that all i get, nothing on it, it should be a multi-layer file like possibly upwards of 10-15 layers if not more. But I get nothing other than 1 layer period. So that is what is con-fuddling me. And it was a no go on the older version of gimp as well.

Comment: Example: https://www.pixelsquid.com/stock-image/square-wooden-crate-1010261998966937049?image=G02   Take that one for instance,  The PNG is worthless to me, it isnt layered.  The PSD is what i need/want, I download it(zip file) then extract it, but then normally one would think that i could jsut dbl click it and poof it will open in gimp with the layers... not so, you will just get 1 white layer/canvas. If you use GIMP try it yourself, it will confuse you too i swear.

Answer (score 1):

Tried downloading the link you pasted, from https://www.pixelsquid.com/stock-image/square-wooden-crate-1010261998966937049?image=G02 (after checking bugmenot.com to "log in"), and it downloaded a zip file `Square%20Wooden%20Crate.G02.2k.psd.zip` and after unzipping `Square_Wooden_Crate_01.G02.2k.psd` I dragged it into GIMP and the wood crate image appeared:

[image: crate in GIMP]

It is still just one "flat" layer, with some darkening around the bottom for it's "shadow," so it's probably not much better than an image from the webpage, but it is fairly high resolution and the white background isn't extremely difficult to make transparent.

This was after I tried downloading the below plugin & copying it to GIMP's plugin directory, but I don't think it did anything. And it doesn't seem to allow the rotating that their website advertises, maybe that's what the plugin does (and probably why it's a 100MB file for an image if a crate).

---

I think I've found the problem... the PixelSquid website has [this info](http://learn.pixelsquid.com/getting-started-with-pixelsquid/) (not super-easy to find, and the plugin link looks like it might be randomly generated):

> Remember to install the free [PixelSquid Photoshop plugin](https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/12824#.VtRnkpMrKRs) and start placing PixelSquid objects directly into your comp!

So, I think you need their special "PixelSquid Photoshop plugin" to use their files. Especially since I don't remember Photoshop or GIMP having a standard rotate feature like they describe *"objects that can be placed and **rotated** right inside of your Photoshop comp. Just click-and-drag to find the perfect angle."*

I'm not too sure if that plugin will work in GIMP...

1. First I tried a google search for [gimp use photoshop plugins](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=gimp+use+photoshop+plugins). Results were inconclusive, so
2. I just tried to download the "PixelSquid Photoshop plugin" to see if just copying it to my GIMP folder would work. Under GIMP's Preferences, in Folders -> Plug-Ins it lists `/home/user/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins` and `/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins` so I was going to try one of those.

   However, problems include:

   1. Have to go to adobe.com to download it, which requires an email & login & password.
   2. After jumping through those hoops, it ***then*** tells me:

      > Congratulations!
      >   Add-on acquired
      >
      > Thanks for using Adobe Add-ons!
      >   Follow these steps to get started:
      >
      > 1. **You need to install the Creative Cloud app in order to install this Add-on**
      > 2. **Click "Get Creative Cloud App"**
      >      Install a compatible app, if needed, and make sure to Sync files to Creative Cloud
      > 3. **Turn on Files Sync** when you've installed Creative Cloud app, your Add-on(s) will be automatically installed
   3. Then it wants me to install the "[Adobe Creative Cloud desktop application](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/desktop-app.html)". I'm not even sure if that's for Windows only (likely), and it's download page won't even load on a near-recent firefox (maybe it's the ad-blocking)

--> Took another look on the plugin's page, and near the bottom there's a "Trouble installing?" section, there's a "[Download (this plugin) using Extension Manager >](https://creative.adobe.com/addons/patches/24413/install)" link, where the actual plugin can be downlaoded, so **FINALLY** got it downloaded. And avoided the "Adobe Creative Cloud desktop application".

BUT, it *may* require another program/plugin, the actual "Extension manager CC" to install it. It's supposed to be here: [Adobe Extension Manager CC](https://www.adobe.com/products/extension-manager.html).

From [GIMP's help on plugins](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-scripting.html#gimp-concepts-plugins) it looks like GIMP's plugins are plain scripts or compile-able programs, probably more than a little different from plain PhotoShop plugins. And my Linux's `file` doesn't even know what the plugin is, aside from data. With a hex editor it looks almost completely random, as if it were *encrypted* or something... maybe it is, with all the trouble it took just to download it, and Adobe wanting it's own program to hold my hand while using it.

I did try [Tor Lillqvist's program "PSPI is a GIMP plug-in that runs 3rd-party Photoshop plug-in filters"](http://the-tml.net/gimp/pspi.html), but using Linux & WINE didn't work out for me (psp.exe.so segfault), and I'm not holding my breath that the Adobe Extension Manager CC would work any better.

At that point, I'm giving up. But at least I think I found the problem - **missing the "PixelSquid Photoshop plugin"**. If you're using **Windows** you should have better luck, since on Linux it's the windows & WINE programs that are giving me trouble. So on Windows the PSPI plugin for GIMP *should* work, and then you can try using the PixelSquid plugin. And the "Adobe Extension Manager CC" program (plugin?) *should* work on Windows too...

Comment: As soon as I saw this,"At that point, I'm giving up...". i got to this.. & I was like...I just laughed least I know it wasent me and i wasent goign nuts! And you are right it is hidden. *sigh* I do have a Win8.1 comp was trying to follow on Nixxy to my windows what you said... and it didn't work there either.   it got close, It turned black instead of white... lol.  But goign through all those steps... I owe you a beer man! Cause I certainly wouldn't have dont what you did. Not thought of it.  Though I cant believe you got farther than i ever did a PICTURE SHOWED UP!!!

Comment: Well, I don't mind not be able to use the files, just kinda disappointing is all.  Oh well, I still appreciate you giving me info that I would never have even thought of and the help you have given me... so you have been a HUGE HELP throughout all this! Thank you so much!  And your patience as well!  I appreciate it a lot.  Hope you have a great day.

Comment: Getting the flat image to appear was actually the *easy* part, and it does work with a plain GIMP (version 2.8.10). I may take another look at the "GIMP use photoshop plugins" problem since that sounds useful no matter what, I'll update if I find out anything. If the answer's useful or "good enough" (or the only one) you could click the check-mark beside it to select it as "correct", and maybe the up arrow to "vote up" it (may need 15 rep first)

Comment: Ok, I actually found a PSD file that works, I guess the PSD from PSq are different in coding? Like the above maybe file encrypted to a point, prob to only work with PS? So the PSD do work perse in GIMP. This PSD is working Both on Nixxy, and Kaitlyn. Both PC's same setup/pic layers etc:  http://i.imgur.com/kSeVKJW.png ~197MB PSD 130layers, so it is possible to open, just not with the PSq files is all. So you are not getting confused, or anything it is supposed to work, but it isnt period. I shouldnt need any other plugins since it is native to the program itself.

Comment: Sorry just realized after re reading this, Nixxy is my Linux Desktop, and Kaitlyn is my Windows PC, I call them by their names,  it is natural to me... My bad for any confusion I caused you...and anyone else what I call my electronics. Heck even my wife gets confused sometimes so my apologies, especially with my Tablets and cellphones, lol makes it even worse but we aint going there.